# facing error in JWT authentication in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, jwt

This is the error I am getting while hitting { http://localhost:3000/users } to create a new user but facing the below issue.

JWT::DecodeError in UsersController#index
Nil JSON web token
Extracted source (around line #12)

```
def jwt_decode (token)
    decoded = JWT.decode(token, SECRET_KEY)[0]
    HashWithIndifferentAccess.new decoded
end




class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    skip_before_action :authenticate_request
    # POST /auth/login
    def login
        @user User.find_by_email (params[:email])
        if @user&.authenticate(params[:password])
            token = jwt_encode(user_id: @user.id)
            render json: { token: token }, status: :ok
        else
            render json: { error: 'unauthorized' }, status: :unauthorized
        end
    end
end


class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    require 'stripe'
  Stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_51O1pqnSCcF3F1d0MklDFQ0DIDSQ366PJh3YVx8AEqZH5OYRDjIMKOQdACJ5dxNiMkAH4dZdAZy48yzp6FKS3KMAy00VB8RVFBI'

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  include JsonWebToken
  before_action :authenticate_request

  private
    def authenticate_request
    header = request.headers["Authorization"]
    header = header.split(" ").last if header
    decoded = jwt_decode(header)
    @current_user= User.find(decoded[:user_id])
    end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  skip_before_action :authenticate_request, only: [:create]
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :destroy]

  def index
   @users = User.all
   render json: @users, status: :ok
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created
    else
      render json:{ errors:  @user.errors.full_messages },
             status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

I have been trying to resolve this issue but unable to do so.

Comment: Token is null, hence there is no Authorization header on your request

Comment: the code is breaking on front end side, even on the signup page. Token is supposed to be generated after signup .

Comment: You run `before_action :authenticate_request` on EVERY request. It expects Authorization header to be present. Voting to close as typo

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `http://localhost:3000/users` through a `GET` request which seems to map the below method.

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  render json: @users, status: :ok
end
```

You have `before_action :authenticate_request` set on your `ApplicationController` which is called before every action (method) of your controllers. So if you are not logged in, you will face an error.

But in you question, you are saying that you are having this error while trying to create a user. So you are actually intending to call `def create` instead of `def index` right?

Maybe try to change your request method type from `GET` to `POST` maybe? I don't know your routes so I am talking based on assumptions.

```
POST http://localhost:3000/users
```